# How start time and end time in fullcalendar are working?

Tags: asp.net-core, fullcalendar

I'm trying to put a start time and end time with fullcalendar in asp.net core like that: (I have a list of SchoolClass)

```
events: [
@foreach (var item in Model.SchoolClass)
{
  @: title: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayClass)',
  @: start: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartTime)',
  @: end: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndTime)',
}
```

I have a SchoolClass.cs:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date of the schoolclass")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime DayClass{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Start time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime StartTime{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "End Time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime EndTime{ get; set; }
```

But there is the result

[image]

I have nothing inside it, and normally I have one.. I guess its the format which is not good ?

Cordially

EDIT: When I put that:

```
  @: title: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayClass)',
  @: start: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayClass)',
  @: end: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayClass)',
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Resolved, thanks for the help :p

Comment: You could add an asnwer and accept it as answer to share us your solution.